# Не находит ссылки PostMapping Spring IntellijIDEA

Tags: java, spring

Почему-то при переходе по ссылке, программа говорит что такой ссылке не существует. В чём может быть проблема. Создал простое приложение для демонстрации.

```
package ru.leaning.test;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```
package controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class Test {

    @PostMapping("/")
    public Integer getTest() {
        System.out.println("test");
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Обновил скрншоты

Post - запрос:

Запуск приложения
[image: Запуск приложения]

Запрос Postman
[image: Запрос Postman]

Ответ приложения на запрос
[image: Реакция приложения на запрос]

Get - запрос:

Запуск приложения
[image: Запуск приложения GetMapping]

Запрос в Postman
[image: Запрос Get-запроса в Postman]

Ответ приложения на запрос
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы создали эндпойнт для POST-запроса, но пытаетесь попасть на него через GET-запрос.

Учитывая, что на самом деле вы ничего не "постите" на этот эндпойнт, поменяйте аннотацию маппинга с `@PostMapping` на `@GetMapping`:

```java
@RestController
public class Test {
    @GetMapping("/") // <- вот здесь
    public Integer getTest() {
        // какой-то код
    }
}
```

Или же в Postman слева от адресной строки поменяйте GET на POST, чтобы попасть на существующий эндпойнт.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ:**

Был не прав, ошибка в другом - класс контроллера просто не виден вашему Spring приложению.
Сделайте так, чтобы директория *"controller"* находилась внутри директории *"ru.learning.test"*.
Дело в том, что класс, помеченный аннотацией `@SpringBootApplication`, по умолчанию включает `@ComponentScan` только для той директории, где находится этот класс, и всех директорий, находящихся внутри нее.
Об этом можно [почитать здесь](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using.structuring-your-code.locating-the-main-class).

Comment: Спасибо, что помогли, исправил неточность. Но к сожалению ошибка не в этом(

Comment: @Hazernit дополнил свой ответ - проблема действительно в другом)

Comment: Спасибо огромное, очень помогли!)